# how to add a transition to a hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a class in which I have the overflow-x hidden.
When hovering over the class, the overflow-x should become visible but with a delay (transition)
I just don't know how to do that:

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
 width: 100% !important;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 font-size: 1em !important;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 background-color: #ddd;

 }

.syntaxhighlighter:hover {
 width: 100% !important;
 overflow-x: visible; /* the visibility should come with a delay  (transition) */ 
 font-size: 1em !important;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 background-color: #ddd;
 }
```

Comment: Explaining the desired "transition" would help, unless you expect people getting creative ;)

Comment: @sinanspd it's possible in CSS using transition if 1. you apply the overflow, and than you animate the width to bring the scrollbar into "view".

Comment: the hover effect should take 2 seconds before totally expanding

Comment: What do you mean by "totally expanding"? Expanding where? You mean like *eeexpaaaaandddd!!!* or a different expand?

Comment: By expanding I mean: I have some code into the class syntaxhighlighter. If the code lines are too long for the area, the code is not totally visible at the right side of it. When hover over the class, the area breaks out to the right and the complete code is visible. And that "break out effect", which is actually a hover state should be delayed with 2 seconds

Comment: ok, so in other words, you want on hover to make your element scrollable (*on hover please add scrollbars*) right? Now, the effect is not clear since you cannot apply effect (fadeIn/out etc) to scrollbars. (Actually you *can*, ofc, using some quite of JS and two overlapping elements, one that has the scrollbars, the other (overlay) having the content.)... or a scrollbars library plugin... but I'm still guessing here.

Comment: see this demo I created for a chat, on hover I apply the scrollbars... http://jsbin.com/iXaWOGUg/3/edit?html,css,js,output But you cannot fade-whatever-transition the scrollbars, at least not using the default OS scrollbars.

Comment: Her is an example of what I mean: hover over the first code block and you see that there is a little delay in it when expanfding to the right. And I was wondering if this effect is also possible with transition when mouseover : http://webprofis.nl/discussion/439/andere-anchors-blokkeren-als-er-eentje-op-actief-staat

Comment: yes, it's possible! You need to animate an overflowing parent width :) inside you put the child with the exceedign width. On parent hover simply animate it's width to match children's :)

Comment: I have come up with a slightly different approach which (I believe) achieves the effect, @nuet is looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/k2481htw/ ... It works by having a transparent duplicate `<div>` (duplicate size, duplicate content) positioned over the top of the original `<div>`. The duplicate div then has a "2 second fade-in" when it is hovered over.

Comment: @Rounin Awesome! This is exactly where I was looking for. Thanks for the solution

Comment: @nuet - I'm glad you like it, I worked quite hard on it! I wonder if we can have your question unlocked from "marked as duplicate" - the answer it points to simply says "overflow is not animatable" - that's not very helpful. If overflow isn't animatable, then how *can* we achieve the desired effect of "adding a transition to a hover"? That's the approach that I took with your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the CSS3 specification, the `overflow` property is not animatable, so specifying `transition-property: overflow-x` will not do anything.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css

Answer (score -1):

```
.syntaxhighlighter:hover{
  transition: ease all 2.0s;
}
```

Comment: well, this is not working. Because the transition should start only in the hover

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What are you talking about? (You've responded to a comment that doesn't exist)

Comment: @nuet try if the hover pseudo does it.